# Pulling supplies, cost from database and multiplying by quantity, returning total in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am overwhelmed, not thinking right trying to write this simple code. I have a select option, which when a supply is selected it should pull the cost from the database and populate the appropriate field. User then enters a quantity and it calculates a total without refreshing the page. the "submit()" value on my cfselect always clears the field, but populates the cost. I don't know how else to save the values without actually submitting the form. My goal is to have 25+ rows that they can select supplies & quantity and it will populate totals for each and then a grand total.

```
<cfquery name="supplies" datasource="application_dev">
    SELECT * FROM supplies
</cfquery>


<cfoutput>
<cfform>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td colspan=3>Additional Supplies</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Supply</td>
        <td>Cost</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><cfinput type="datefield" name="date_01"></td>
        <td><cfselect name="supply_01" onchange="submit()">
                <option value="0"></option>
            <cfloop query="supplies">
                <option value="#supplies.id#">#supplies.supply#</option>
            </cfloop>
            </cfselect>
        </td>
        <cfif isdefined("form.supply_01")>
            <cfquery name="supply_cost" datasource="application_dev">
                SELECT unitCost FROM supplies
                WHERE id = #form.supply_01#
            </cfquery>
            <td><cfinput type="integer" name="unitCost_01" readonly="yes" value="#supply_cost.unitCost#"></td>
        <cfelse>
            <td><cfinput type="text" readonly="yes" name="null"></td>
        </cfif>
        <td><cfinput type="integer" name="quantity_01" validateat="onBlur"></td>
        <cfif (isdefined("form.quantity_01") AND isdefined("form.unitCost_01"))>
            <cfset totalSum_01 = (LSParseNumber(#form.quantity_01#) * LSParseNumber(#form.unitCost_01#))>
            <td><cfinput type="integer" readonly="yes" name="total_01" value="#totalSum_01#"></td>
        <cfelse>
            <td><cfinput type="integer" readonly="yes" name="null"></td>
        </cfif>
        </tr>
    </table>
</cfform>  
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Have you heard of Ajax or jQuery?

Comment: Both of which are subsets of javascript.

Comment: I have heard of, but never learned the two languages. I was trying to avoid using anything but CFML

Comment: @bWF800 you can't avoid them if you want anything along the line of "without actually submitting the form"

Comment: Actually, you can do this with ColdFusion only.  If you read the documentation on cfselect, cfinput, etc, you will notice a bind attribute.

Comment: Start by joining the supply and unitcost table together in your initial select so you have the prices included in the initial query.  Then it's just a matter of putting in a hidden field or custom attribute that you can access via JavaScript later.  And since you're asking for this to all happen client side, you must use JS one way or another.